# Font files not loading in Drupal site running in Azure Server

Tags: azure, drupal, url-rewriting, web-config

Here's a font file that resides in the server. But it seems to be throwing 404

[image]

And here's the `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory. -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />

    <!--
       Caching configuration was not delegated by default. Some hosters may not
       delegate the caching configuration to site owners by default and that
       may cause errors when users install. Uncomment this if you want to and
       are allowed to enable caching.
     -->
    <!--
    <caching>
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".php" policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
        <add extension=".html" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="14:00:00" />
      </profiles>
    </caching>
     -->

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Protect files and directories from prying eyes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="\.(engine|inc|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format|composer\.(json|lock)|\.htaccess)$" />
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" subStatusCode="0" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Access is forbidden." />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="favicon\.ico" />
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" subStatusCode="1" statusReason="File Not Found" statusDescription="The requested file favicon.ico was not found" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
    <!-- To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
     http://example.com/foo will be redirected to http://www.example.com/foo)
     adapt and uncomment the following:   -->
    <!--
        <rule name="Redirect to add www" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    -->

    <!-- To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
     http://www.example.com/foo will be redirected to http://example.com/foo)
     adapt and uncomment the following:   -->
    <!--
        <rule name="Redirect to remove www" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    -->

        <!-- Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem
         to index.php. -->
        <rule name="Short URLS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

  <!-- If running Windows Server 2008 R2 this can be commented out -->
    <!-- httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/index.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors -->

    <defaultDocument>
     <!-- Set the default document -->
      <files>
         <clear />
        <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Site is running in an Azure Server. And my guess is that it is because of some rewrite rules, which am not able to figure out. Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding [MIME Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap) for the static content.

ie, after the `</defaultDocument>`, add the following lines:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css" />      
</staticContent>
```